# TypeScript mapped object type Including "length" and other properties from tuple when it shouldn't

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Per [the TypeScript documentation on mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html), if I create a fixed-length tuple type like so:

```ts
type FixedList = [string, number, boolean];
```

and then I create a generic I intend to pass this type into:

```ts
type SomeGeneric<T> = {
  propOne: number;
  propTwo: string;
  propThree(arg0: T): void;
};
```

I should be able to create a mapped object type

```ts
type GenericFixedList = {
  [K in keyof FixedList]: SomeGeneric<FixedList[K]>;
};
```

and then, if I have some correctly-sized array, I should be able to do this:

```ts
const stronglyTypedList: GenericFixedList = [
  {
    propOne: 0,
    propTwo: "zero",
    propThree(arg0) {},
  },
  // ... etc
];
```

However, when doing this I get this error:

```
... is not assignable to type GenericFixedList:
  types of property 'length' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type SomeGeneric<3>.
```

Which indicates to me that, in spite of the documentation explicitly calling out that `length` should be ignored when constructing this tuple type, for some reason the array length of 3 from `keyof FixedList` is getting passed to the mapped object type, producing the type constraint `length: SomeGeneric<3>`, which of course is incompatible with an array.

I've tried specifying `Omit<FixedList, "length">` but the problem just moves to the next array property (the iterator function for `for in`/`for of`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please make this a [mre] without `AnotherType` in it? Presumably you can just put native types in there without changing the issue.

Comment: This is considered a bug in TypeScript, reported at [ms/TS#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  Currently mapped tuples only happen properly when the type you're mapping over is *generic*.  Until and unless this is fixed, you get the desired behavior through indirection [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WzkxEw). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, you found it. I don't know why my Googling couldn't find this exact issue, it's a bit embarrassing. Your explanation and solution worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm going to [edit] your code to be a [mre] as I asked in my first comment; hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  Apparently the support for [mapping array types to array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) only works when the input type is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and otherwise you get the weird behavior of mapping over all the array methods and properties as well.  The lead architect for TypeScript [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847) that they "should probably also [map to tuples and arrays] for homomorphic mapped types with a `keyof T` where `T` is [a] non-generic type", but so far nothing has been done about it.  It's been five years so it's not clear when or if this will ever be fixed.

Until and unless that happens, you can work around it by a layer of generic indirection, as shown here:

```
type MapSomeGeneric<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: SomeGeneric<T[K]> }

type FixedList = [string, number, boolean];

type GenericFixedList = MapSomeGeneric<FixedList>
/* type GenericFixedList = [
     SomeGeneric<string>, 
     SomeGeneric<number>, 
     SomeGeneric<boolean>
] */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygewLZQOJQHZQE4EsDGAPACoB8MAvDAN7AwwTYIQDyWAXDBgK5IBGOANx0GTCMQDuCTgGcQeDAHNh9Rs2IALbFCgAKAIbZFABk7EAlJwBuCXABNhAX2GhIsALL6IiFOix4iMkoRahgAbQBpGFwMGABrKDAEADMYYgBdTh80TBwCEkj08kdgV2gYADFcAA8oOwAZXDlKcLkFRQAaLl4BbC6+BAQAGyh9DHSXcHK-PPwq2oamkBbPb2Qc-3z5usa5UmAAegAqGCnYGYDtxeaqMJF6eHWL-LaYxVIu+-ps56IefhwHxgX0evlyAUIA2Goww+3SMCOB2AQA)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```js
type GenericFixedList = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof FixedList, keyof any[]>]: SomeGeneric<FixedList[K]>;
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdge2ACwgJwCrmgXigbwCgooBnBAWwgHkAjAKwgGNgAxASwgBsATALgLESZShAAiECJDQdu-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-ruwC6kBdggeaV4QXeQiwbKwhnquAgAMyoduv6LCg5rYaRaGgfhN6ETBcLPmRb4ACzUSaO5-qECCKGgjFbueeHgWxUFERyXIAPQKVAAACwCkAAtBAAyQCwWloAqaC9v2c6hFo7BcKQk7CtOBYhsW85PvBipvhuzkCbRB4KuJL5aix0mQcRxFcQhAifu56F-gBPm4ZeAXsQEnHueRyH8ZFdFYWl-nXoFRFJThoWpRFgkZUeWVSTlCWPhyQA)